# JS - Convert \u00e9 in é (Json encoding to arabic or latin)

Tags: node.js, json, character-encoding

i scrape request with puppeteer. I having scraping a text encoding in JSON ( \u00e9 and not é, \u00e0 and not à ...).
I must modify  transform the text to use it    \u00e9 --> é, \u00e0 --> à....

I read the file and transform in string in order to use a regex. After i write the file

```
var str = fs.readFileSync('./tmp/response.json');
const matches = str.toString('latin1').matchAll(regexp);
....
fs.writeFileSync('./tmp/bdd.txt', resp, { flag: 'a+' },  'latin1');
```

i already use `json.parse` but there is a problem because is not a valid JSON.
i already use   `toString('latin1')` and `toString('utf8')` but no effect.

i have find this module but there is an error when i want use it. "TypeError: utf8ToAnsi is not a function"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8-to-ansi

```
    var utf8ToAnsi = require("utf8-to-ansi")
    const utf8 = 'สวัสดีชาวโลก'
    const ansi = utf8ToAnsi(utf8)
    console.log(ansi)
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

i solve the problem with this API [Node Native2ascii](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-native2ascii)

```
  str = native2ascii(str, { reverse: true });
```